# How do I disable output buffering while still preserving my site's appearance?

Tags: 7, theming

Whenever I try disabling output buffering, my site's layout gets displayed incorrectly. Why is that and is it possible to disable output buffering without wrecking my layout? Thanks.

edit 1:

I edited [theme.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/7) (a Drupal's core file) and commented out `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`. This results in all the content that's supposed to appear between the <body> tags being printed before the <html> tag. This is also the outcome if I replace ob_get_clean with ob_get_flush. Replacing it with ob_get_contents returns only the content without the <body> tags and everything else outside of it.

edit 2:

Did some further editing and I think I found out why turning output buffering off results in layout problems. The sequence in which the template files are called is not necessarily in the same order as they're supposed to appear. In fact, the file with the <html>, <head>, and <body> tags is called last. I don't know if that's normal or if it's because of my theme. In any case, it looks like disabling output buffering isn't an option for me.

Comment: Output buffering was something I've never used before. Commenting out ob_start and ob_get_clean from theme.inc resulted in messed up layouts. When I check the source, the location of the code is all wrong. Everything that's supposed to be between the <body> tags instead appears before the <html> tag.

Comment: *Actually,* this is how Drupal works with any and all `tpl.php` templates: inside `theme_render_template()` it  extracts the `$variables` array, turns on buffering, includes/runs the template and then returns (and cleans up) the resulting output that has been buffered.  Later on Drupal then puts this buffered content in where it belongs, whether that is `$page` or any other variable that is created from a template.  So, turning all of this off will exhibit the odd behavior displayed.  And that would be best described as "by design."

Comment: I reopened this, as it can be edited a bit to make it more Drupal-centric, and it can have a good Drupal answer.

Comment: @Jimajamma seems you are the best guy to do what MPD wrote. And I'll be glad to upvote your answer if you'll post it.